# Toilet leaking from base

Tags: toilet, bathtub, washer

Toilet leaking from base of toilet when flushed . Just washed a load of clothes. When washer drained water came up through toilet and bath tub . What could it be?!

Comment: how old is your house?  could be tree roots if you have segmented clay pipes or the city section does.  Could be someone flushed something they shouldn't have, I've seen thermometers, plastic toys, non decomposable wipes ( for some great vids check out the penetrator on youtube it is disgusting but SFW ).

Answer (score 11):

The fact that the washer drain is coming up through the toilet leads me to believe that you have a clogged drain pipe at some point BELOW the point where the toilet drain enters your drain stack.

The water is backup up and then forcing its way past the toilet flange seal.  That seal is not designed to handle water pressure.

You'll either need to buy or rent the tools needed to locate and then remove the blockage or hire a plumber to do it for you.

Answer (score 5):

Washer drains large amount of water in short time.

You drain is clogged or partially clogged and can not handle that.

Since it is already leaking under the toilet, you will have to remove the toilet, unscrew and lift it out and place on two 2x4 supports. Remove the wax seal and clean the residue on the toilet flange.

Then proceed in using a drain snake in a attempt to remove the clog. Or maybe you have to use more sophisticated tools to inspect the drain line, like a camera to find it. You might have to inspect the drain where it exits the home. Usually there is screw on cap on drain-Y to do that.

Unfortunately you might be facing some serious damage from the leak. The floor if it is wood will be damaged, the toilet mount ring needs to be replaced also. This all would be a DIY job but if you are not confident get a plumber.

Comment: I had to do this once. Fortunately the house had a flat roof and I used the snake down a vent pipe. Therefore I did not need to remove the toilet. BUT... water leaking from under the toilet means that the toilet is not sealed properly to the pipe and needs repair.

Answer (score 4):

You have a clog. Diagnosing where online will be impossible. This is something you cannot repair on your own. You need to call a plumber.

Comment: Because only a plumber could possibly push a snake through a clean out?

Comment: @FreshCodemonger OP's question phrasing suggests little plumbing experience. There are a range of possible types of clogs and possible damage to the toilet seal, so hiring a professional seems the wise choice in this case at least.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger  Because pushing the clog from above will just compress it more. It needs to be pulled apart from the dry (down-slope) side with a corkscrew attachment, and trapped at the downstream access point so it can be removed from the drainage system (before it ends up at somewhere even less accessible). If it is big and solid enough to block a 4-inch soil pipe, it is too serious for a novice to deal with.